# Issue with gravity forms uploading images as featured image and acf gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am really struggling to get the images from a gravity form entry to upload as a featured image and to acf gallery field. I have tried many different versions but right now this is the current version I have running but not working

```
function process_attached_listing( $order_id ) {
    $order             = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user_id           = $order->get_user_id();

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $listing_entry = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_listing_entry', true );
        $product_id    = $item->get_product_id();
        $variation_id  = $item->get_variation_id();

        if ( ! empty( $variation_id ) ) {
            $product_id = $variation_id;
        }

    }
    $result = GFAPI::get_entry( $listing_entry );
    if ( $result ) {

            $gallery_images       = [];
            $listing_title        = rgar( $result, '9' );//
            $listing_description  = rgar( $result, '10' );//
            $images               = rgar( $result, '5' );//
            $condition            = 'New' == rgar( $result, '45' ) ? 1 : 0;
            $quick_sale           = rgar( $result, '117.1' );
            $open_to_offers       = rgar( $result, '116.1' );


            $data = [
                'post_title'   => $listing_title,
                'post_content' => $listing_description,
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_type'    => 'main-listing',
                'post_author'  => $user_id,
            ];

            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
                // Set images START
                $uploaded_images_array = explode(',', $images);
                $featured_image_id = attachment_url_to_postid($uploaded_images_array[0]);
                set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $featured_image_id)
                $image_ids = array_map('attachment_url_to_postid', $uploaded_images_array);
                // Set images END

                $orders   = get_field( 'field_642416d69042a', $post_id, false );
                $orders[] = $order_id;

                update_field( 'field_641afeecd0da3', $condition, $post_id );
                update_field( 'field_641affe5d0db1', $quick_sale, $post_id ); 
                update_field( 'field_641afffad0db2', $open_to_offers, $post_id );
                update_field( 'field_641afeccd0da2', $image_ids, $post_id );

            } else {
                error_log( $post_id->get_error_message() );
            }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'process_attached_listing', 10, 1 );
```

any help or guidance would be hugely appreciated

Comment: First off, where is the value for the variable $listing_entry defined?

Comment: It looks like you're generating the post programmatically rather than using Gravity Forms' Advanced Post Creation add-on but if you're willing to make the switch there, this tutorial will do all of the heavy lifting for you:

https://gravitywiz.com/advanced-custom-fields-gallery-post-creation/

Comment: @Rochelle My apologies, I stripped a lot of the other code down from this and accidently removed the section defining it

Comment: @DavefromGravityWiz That is very interesting, the issue I face is there are a lot of other calculations and data manipulation that happens on completed wc transaction, thus we opted for it programmatically. I would be happy to explore the option if I can set when the post is created (9asin our case on wc completed transaction hook) and can set custom calculations for certain ACF fields